# Google API error

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to use google API to get events off calendars on an account. I am using a service account. I am receiving two errors when I attempt to manually echo the code or it will remain a blank page if I use foreach(...).
Here are the two errors:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList/primary: (404) Not Found' in C:\wamp\www\newOLP\scripts\oAuth2\Google\Http\REST.php on line 110
( ! ) Google_Service_Exception: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList/primary: (404) Not Found in C:\wamp\www\newOLP\scripts\oAuth2\Google\Http\REST.php on line 110
```

Here is my code:

```
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
   session_start();     
/************************************************   
 The following 3 values an befound in the setting   
 for the application you created on Google      
 Developers console.         Developers console.
 The Key file should be placed in a location     
 that is not accessable from the web. outside of 
 web root.   

 In order to access your GA account you must    
 Add the Email address as a user at the     
 ACCOUNT Level in the GA admin.         
 ************************************************/
$client_id = $jsonDecode['client_id'];
    $Email_address = $jsonDecode['client_email'];    
    $key_file_location = 'privateKey.p12';      

    $client = new Google_Client();      
    $client->setApplicationName("CalCon");
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);    

// separate additional scopes with a comma   
$scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";   
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(    
    $Email_address,      
    array($scopes),     
    $key         
    );      
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {        
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);       
}       
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);    

?>

<html><body>

<?php
$calendarList  = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
echo $service->calendars->get('primary')->getSummary()."<br />";
echo $service->calendarList->get('primary')->getSummary();
while(true) {
    foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
            echo $calendarListEntry;
            echo "hi";
            echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary()."<br>\n";


            // get events 
            $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarListEntry->id);


            foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
                echo "-----".$event->getSummary()."<br>";
            }
        }
        $pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();
        if ($pageToken) {
            $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
            $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Have you tried going to "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList/primary" manually in a browser and seeing if it loads for you?

Comment: Hm...No I haven't. It says login require.

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}

Comment: You are trying GET so you can add params to url.  I would set break point on line 110 where the error is generated and work out why its getting a 404.

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function getSummary() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\newOLP\scripts\oAuth2\oAuthPhp.php on line 65

Comment: Find the line calling getSummary() and figure out why its not in scope or if there is an argument that's not instantiated.  The error tells you where to go, follow the trail until you find the cause of the issue

Comment: Okay. I'll do it tomorrow.. Terrible headache all day. :/ thanks for the help so far!